# How do I perform a replacement using a formatted string from a regex capture group?

Tags: regex, rust

I am doing multiple replacements at once using the regex crate:

```
extern crate regex;

use regex::{Captures, Regex};

fn transform(string: &str) {
    let rgx = Regex::new(r"(\n)|(/\w+)").unwrap();
    let res = rgx.replace_all(string, |caps: &Captures| {
        if caps.get(1).is_some() {
            return " ";
        }
        match caps.get(2).map(|m: regex::Match| m.as_str()) {
            Some(z) => return "nope", // how to return formatted z instead?
            None => (),
        }
        unreachable!();
    });
    println!("{}", res);
}

fn main() {
    transform("no errors");
    transform("big\nbad\n/string");
}
```

Output as expected:

```
no errors
big bad nope
```

Instead of "nope", I would like to return `z` formatted in some way instead. `format!` doesn't seem like it can be used here due to `String` / lifetime issues:

```
match caps.get(2).map(|m: regex::Match| m.as_str()) {
    Some(z) => return format!("cmd: {}", z),
    None => (),
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:12:31
   |
12 |             Some(z) => return format!("cmd: {}", z),
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected &str, found struct `std::string::String`
   |
   = note: expected type `&str`
              found type `std::string::String`
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate (in Nightly builds, run with -Z external-macro-backtrace for more info)
```

What should be done instead?

Comment: `String` doesn't have a lifetime, so it would just work. What errors did you have when you tried?

Comment: Please note how I've edited your question to *show* the code you've tried, as well as copying in the *entire error message*. Please take care to provide information in similar ways for all future questions as it's a very effective way to communicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note in the error message:

> expected `&str`

It expects a `&str` because that's the first type returned by your closure:

> ```
> return " ";
> ```

A closure / function can have only one return type, not two.

The simplest fix is to return a `String` in both cases:

```
let res = rgx.replace_all(string, |caps: &Captures| {
    if caps.get(1).is_some() {
        return String::from(" ");
    }
    let m = caps.get(2).unwrap();
    format!("cmd: {}", m.as_str())
});
```

To be slightly more efficient, you can avoid the `String` allocation for the space character:

```
use std::borrow::Cow;
```

```
let res = rgx.replace_all(string, |caps: &Captures| {
    if caps.get(1).is_some() {
        return Cow::from(" ");
    }
    let m = caps.get(2).unwrap();
    Cow::from(format!("cmd: {}", m.as_str()))
});
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dba4289e1630fa2d9b6f9f76b7750ed8)

I've also replaced the `match` with the `=> ()` arm paired with the `unreachable!` with the shorter `unwrap`.

See also:

- [Cannot use `replace_all` from the regex crate: expected (), found String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39135477/155423)
- [Using str and String interchangably](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31240091/155423)
- [Return local String as a slice (&str)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29428227/155423)